# Open Cart 3 '/add' path in Admin pannel

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I'm currently developping an e-shop for the first time using Open Cart.

I added a custom page in the 'Catalog' subcategory of the Admin menu 
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVPup.png).

To have this, I copied the files from 'product' in all four admin subfolders (controller, language, model and view) and renamed everything. I have two twig files, one from product_list and one from product_form.

The aim of this new Admin catalog page is to list the characters from a database I created. I modified the content of the different .php and .twig pages to match my content, and the page behaves as I wanted, listing the characters. I kept the 'add', 'copy', 'delete' and 'edit' buttons from the Product page, but now I have a problem.

When clicking on these buttons on the Product page, they bring you to a '`admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/add&user_token=`' or '`admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/copy&user_token=`', and they work fine. 
But, if I click them on my new page, these types of links bring to nothing.

I have the links declared in my controller file, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqkhJ.png)

From what I understand, the link in the Menu calls onto the product_list.twig, while the 'add' page calls to the product_form.twig. But it is not explained anywhere visible how that link is made. 
The 'Category' link in the menu works the same, where the buttons will bring to such links.

I am guessing there must be a line somwhere within the OpenCart files that declares that name_form will be called when the buttons are clicked, 
I tried looking through different files to find something like that but got no luck.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ?

The reason I want this is so my future user can go into the admin panel and add new characters to the database instead of having to go into the database itself.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share the [relevant parts of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you have developed so far. This helps figuring out what the problem could be. Also please edit your question to have necessary pictures be displayed inline. For help see ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Trying to identify the relevant parts helped me. I was missing a `$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('catalog/killer_evening_form', $data));` line at the end of the `getForm()` function in the controller. 

As for necessary pictures, I am not allowed to have them inline yet, which is why they are in links instead of on display, sorry for that. Thank you for directing me towards identifying my problem !

Comment: To place an image in your post, just place an exclamation mark in front of the link, See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images. I don't think a privilege is needed for this. Once you earned https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user, you will be able to post more than eight hyperlinks at a time, but I don't think the kind of hyperlink is restricted in some way. Just try it ;-)